# How to append multiple child elements in the DOM and display them, using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, shadow-dom, appendchild, documentfragment

I am trying to insert some SVG icons in the dom but the SVG(parent node) is always being replaced by the use(child node). Anyone help me figure it out?

[Source code Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVnly.jpg)

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/evangeloskolimitras/pen/oOExEY?editors=1011)

```
const icons = [
    "html5" ,
    "css3" ,
    "javascript" ,
    "bootstrap" ,
    "sass" ,
    "node" ,
    "mongodb" ,
    "d3" ,
    "react" ,
    "webpack" ,
    "wordpress"
];

const tech_icons = document.querySelector( "#techs__icons" );

icons.forEach( icon=> {

    const svg = document.createElement( "svg" );
    const use = document.createElement( "use" );

        svg.setAttribute( "class" , `techs__icon icon icon-${icon}` );
    use.setAttribute( "href" , `./src/images/sprites.svg#icon-${icon}` );

    tech_icons.appendChild( use ).appendChild( use );

} );
```

I can successfully log them in the console but they don't seem to appear on the document.

I appended it already to the parent node (techs_icons) but can't figure it out at this point!

> **UPDATED CODE**

```
icons.forEach( icon=> {

    const tech_icons = document.querySelector( "#techs__icons" );

    const svg = document.createElement( "svg" );
    svg.setAttribute( "class" , `techs__icon icon icon-${icon}` );
    const use = document.createElement( "use" );
    use.setAttribute( "href" , `./src/images/sprites.svg#icon-${icon}` );

    svg.appendChild( use );

    tech_icons.appendChild( svg );

} );
```

[This snapshot seems to work here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu0xY.jpg)

Still won't be displayed in the DOM. Actually, they are being appended because when I hover them over in the inspector they are there but not visible.

> **SECOND UPDATE TO THE CODE**

It looks like you need to create some kind of "fake" element inside my svg>use>"fake element", like a shadowRoot which i actually do not understand why the browser creates such an element when importing SVG files!

I figured it out when inspecting the element and saw that the browser actually creates automatically that shadow.

***SVG***

```
<symbol id="icon-html5">
   <path d="M2 0h28l-2.547 28.751-11.484 3.249-11.419-3.251-2.551-28.749zM11.375 13l-0.309-3.624 13.412 0.004 0.307-3.496-17.568-0.004 0.931 10.68h12.168l-0.435 4.568-3.88 1.072-3.94-1.080-0.251-2.813h-3.479l0.44 5.561 7.229 1.933 7.172-1.924 0.992-10.876h-12.789z"/>
 </symbol>
```

[Inspected code showing the auto created shadow element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y981g.jpg)

```
const tech_icons = document.querySelector( "#techs__icons" );
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

icons.forEach( icon => {

    const svg = document.createElement( "svg" );
    const use = document.createElement( "use" );
    let shadow = use.attachShadow( { mode : open } );

    svg.setAttribute( "class" , `techs__icon icon icon-${icon}` );
    use.setAttribute( "href" , `./src/images/sprites.svg#icon-${icon}` );
    shadow.appendChild( "I am a: child element inside shadowroot (svg>use>shadowroot>ME)" );

   svg.appendChild( use );

   fragment.appendChild( svg );

});

tech_icons.appendChild( fragment );
```

So at this point to recap:

1. Added the result for the forEach() loop to a document fragment and after that loop ended i appended that fragment as a child to the real DOM element (.techs_info)
2. Created a shadow and also append it as a child to the use element

Problem still exists, while when appending the shadow to the use element neither the DOM or the console does not actually display anything!

Comment: Why you append use two times?

Comment: Maybe you want to use ` appendChild(svg)` ?

Comment: You cannot manipulate the DOM of an iframe this way. Your code runs in an iframe whenever you use Codepen.

Comment: The problem is not happening only in the code pen.

Comment: @El. i am just appending the use child to the svg parent and then i append the svg child which is the parent of the use child to the parent techs_icons. so its a bit like this    techs_icons > svg > use

Comment: No, you never append `svg` anywhere? [mcve] !

Comment: 1. remove obsolete code. 2. use createElementNS()

Comment: @Supersharp what you mean obsolete code my friend? :D

Comment: @Evan the 1st part is wrong and you corrected it by an update => remove it

Answer (score 1):

SVG elements are not standard HTML so you'll need to specify the SVG namespace in the `createElementNS()` method:

```
const svg = document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg' )
const use = document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use' )
```

Also in the SVG source file you must specify the namespace in the `xmlns` attribute:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<symbol id="icon-html5">
   <path d="M2 0h28l-2.547 28.751-11.484 3.249-11.419-3.251-2.551-28.749zM11.375 13l-0.309-3.624 13.412 0.004 0.307-3.496-17.568-0.004 0.931 10.68h12.168l-0.435 4.568-3.88 1.072-3.94-1.080-0.251-2.813h-3.479l0.44 5.561 7.229 1.933 7.172-1.924 0.992-10.876h-12.789z"/>
 </symbol> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
componentDidMount (){

    const script = document.createElement("script");
    const script1 = document.createElement("script");
    const script2 = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = 'assets/js/jquery.showmore.js';
    script1.src = 'assets/js/showmore.js';
    script2.src = 'assets/js/owl-carousel.js';
    script.async = true;
    script1.async = true;
    script2.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
    document.body.appendChild(script1);
    document.body.appendChild(script2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your Codepen using this corrected code:

```
const icons = [
    "html5" ,
    "css3" ,
    "javascript" ,
    "bootstrap" ,
    "sass" ,
    "node" ,
    "mongodb" ,
    "d3" ,
    "react" ,
    "webpack" ,
    "wordpress"
];

icons.forEach( icon=> {
    const tech_icons = document.getElementById( "techs__icons" );

    const svg = document .createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svg.setAttribute( "class" , `techs__icon icon icon-${icon}` );

    const use = document .createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
    use.setAttribute( "xlink:href" , `./src/images/sprites.svg#icon-${icon}` );

    svg.appendChild( use );

    tech_icons.appendChild( svg );

  console.log(tech_icons);
} );
```

When inspecting in the console, the SVG elements are created and occupy space in the DIV in the document but they seems to be empty or invisible. So I blame the sprites.svg file.

Comment: The problem my friend is that i already tested the sprites and are working fine! I mean i had it previously hard coded all the icons and now i am trying to add them dynamically to the DOM.

Comment: Where can I access the .svg file in your Codepen? I couldn't find it. Maybe I could investigate a little more with it on hands.

Comment: Hey @igreka i just updated the post. It includes also the svg source code.

Answer (score -1):

```
var mylist = document.getElementById("myList")
list.forEach(item){
var node = document.createElement("LI");                 // Create a <li> node
var textnode = document.createTextNode(item);         // Create a text node
node.appendChild(textnode);                          // Append the text to <li>
mylist.appendChild(node) //Append to<Ul> id="myList"
}
```

Comment: also ur using  tech_icons.appendChild( use ).appendChild( use );// use twice i think you should be using svg and use

Comment: This has syntax errors, and does not answer the question?

Comment: Maybe you want to use ` appendChild(svg)` ?    thats wat i meant with the comment like u said earlier @jonas wilms

Comment: Yes, that is a typo. The question should be closed as such. There is no long term value from this question.